# Lost color information when calling git from c#

Tags: c#, git, powershell, msysgit

I am just having a play with a bit of c# and Msysgit's git.exe and have come across a missing color problem. I have a very simple console program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo Msysgit = new ProcessStartInfo();
        Msysgit.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Msysgit.UseShellExecute = false;
        Msysgit.RedirectStandardError = true;
        Msysgit.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        Msysgit.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe";//Msysgit default location       
        Msysgit.Arguments = "log --graph --format=format:\"%C(bold blue) %x08%h\" "; //git command
        Msysgit.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\git\posh-git";//repo to test with

        using (Process gitProcess = new Process())
        {
            gitProcess.StartInfo = Msysgit;
            gitProcess.Start();
            string gitout = gitProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            Console.WriteLine(gitout);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

And this produces the following:
*
*   (Esc)[1;34m2490619
|\
| *   (Esc)[1;34me81889e
| |\
| | * (Esc)[1;34mab09e6b
| |/
| * (Esc)[1;34m16bbe4c

Now I can see the ANSI escape sequence [1;34m for the color blue as applied to the SHA-1 and as requested in the git command; but what has happened to the color information associated with the output from the --graph part of the git command, ie specifically to the pipes and slashes. When the same call is made to git.exe from Powershell the graph is displayed colored as well as the blue SHA-1.

My overall intention here is to capture the output from git.exe, apply a bit of c# processing, and then send the modifyed output to Powershell. Similarly saving the output in Powershell also loses the graph color information even though the color is correctly displayed on screen.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097311/parsing-ansi-escape-codes

Comment: Thank you Jared, some interesting discussions there. My issue is slighlty different insofar as it does not relate to the interpretation of the ansi-escape-codes but rather to the fact that they have gone missing from the graph information sent from git.exe